# Flutter TextField Mac Address Auto Format

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, mac-address

Is there a way to auto format a textfield into Mac Address Format?
Like after every two characters user input, a ':' will be inserted automatically and after 16 characters (excluding the ':') the textfield won't accept anymore characters.